# I want to iterate a JSON object that has changing key name in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop

my json looks like this :

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-09-18",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2018-09-18": {
        "1. open": "112.1900",
        "2. high": "113.6950",
        "3. low": "111.7200",
        "4. close": "113.2100",
        "5. volume": "22114532"
    },
    "2018-09-17": {
        "1. open": "113.6900",
        "2. high": "113.7000",
        "3. low": "111.8600",
        "4. close": "112.1400",
        "5. volume": "20736516"
    },
    "2018-09-14": {
        "1. open": "113.3600",
        "2. high": "113.7300",
        "3. low": "112.4400",
        "4. close": "113.3700",
        "5. volume": "19122349"
    }
```

For a Json file like this, when I use for-loop to get to "Time Series (Daily)" part, how can I find "1. open" of each day as the date is changing everytime.

Comment: If you've managed to get that key, you then loop over its keys/values using `.items()` which'll give you a key of the data, a value of the dictionary for that date, you can then access the value['1. open'] to get the value... of that...?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.items()` and iterate

**Ex:**

```
d = {'Meta Data': {'1. Information': 'Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes', '4. Output Size': 'Compact', '5. Time Zone': 'US/Eastern', '2. Symbol': 'MSFT', '3. Last Refreshed': '2018-09-18'}, 'Time Series (Daily)': {'2018-09-18': {'5. volume': '22114532', '4. close': '113.2100', '2. high': '113.6950', '1. open': '112.1900', '3. low': '111.7200'}, '2018-09-14': {'5. volume': '19122349', '4. close': '113.3700', '2. high': '113.7300', '1. open': '113.3600', '3. low': '112.4400'}, '2018-09-17': {'5. volume': '20736516', '4. close': '112.1400', '2. high': '113.7000', '1. open': '113.6900', '3. low': '111.8600'}}}

for k, v in d["Time Series (Daily)"].items():
    print(v['1. open'])
```

**Output:**

```
112.1900
113.3600
113.6900
```